# D3js pack-layout visualization of generated json file does not work

Tags: json, d3.js, svg, circle-pack

A friend wrote a program in VBA, which generates a json data. I am trying to visualize that data via the pack-layout. We extracted the rules by what the json data is being created from the json data here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535

I went through the data many times myself, I just can't seem to find the problem why it is not being visualized. The browser console claims a problem in line 33 with the token "]" but in my eyes the parenthesis are right and I can't seem to find another mistake.

The visualization works properly with the data from where we extracted the rules.

The question now is, which mistake in the json file prevents the code from being visualized?

Would be amazing if somebody can see this, since we cannot see it. Thanks in advance!

The generated json data looks like this:

```
{
 "name": "While",
 "children": [
  {"name": "While", "size": 27},
  {
   "name": "If",
   "children": [
    {"name": "If", "size": 22},
    {
     "name": "If",
     "children": [
      {"name": "If", "size": 3}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "If",
     "children": [
      {"name": "If", "size": 3}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "If",
     "children": [
      {"name": "If", "size": 3}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "If",
     "children": [
      {"name": "If", "size": 3}
     ]
    },
   ]
  },
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two commas(`,`) at the end of some arrays within that JSON of yours - that makes it invalid and prone to errors.

Just edit it and it will work. Use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to check.

The error lies with the script that generates it :)

Here's the fixed version of your JSON:

```
{
    "name": "While",
    "children": [{
        "name": "While",
        "size": 27
    }, {
        "name": "If",
        "children": [{
            "name": "If",
            "size": 22
        }, {
            "name": "If",
            "children": [{
                "name": "If",
                "size": 3
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "If",
            "children": [{
                "name": "If",
                "size": 3
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "If",
            "children": [{
                "name": "If",
                "size": 3
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "If",
            "children": [{
                "name": "If",
                "size": 3
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Just saw your answer. Will check it out immediatally! Thanks for your time and effort. The site you mentioned prolly will help me a lot in the future too. :-)